# Draw on canvas just start Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to draw a test line on a canvas from a custom view. It works when I call my method `drawBeats()`, for example by pressing a button, but I want to execute `drawBeats()` through `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` when the app is started. Here are the relevant lines of my custom view:

```
    public MetronomeBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ...
        width = this.getWidth();
        height = this.getHeight();

        onMeasure(width, height);
        onSizeChanged(width, height,100, 100);
        onDraw(drawCanvas);
    }

    public void drawBeats() {
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);
        drawPaint.setColor(0xFFAAA9A9);
        drawCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 30, drawPaint);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int desiredWidth = 100;
        int desiredHeight = 100;

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //Measure Width
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            width = widthSize;
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //MATCH_PARENT
            width = Math.max(desiredWidth, widthSize);
        } else {
            width = desiredWidth;
        }

        //Measure Height
        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            height = heightSize;
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //MATCH_PARENT
            height = Math.max(desiredHeight, heightSize);
        } else {
            height = desiredHeight;
        }

        //MUST CALL THIS
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    }
}
```

And here's how I call `drawBeats()` from `MainActivity`:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           ...
            mBar = findViewById(R.id.mBar);
            ...
            mBar.drawBeats();
        }
```

I need to force `onMeasure()`, `onSizeChanged()` and `onDraw()` in order to draw on canvases that are not empty. I tried with `drawBeats()` inside of a thread as well. Canvas' background is visible from the beginning.
I just want to draw something just opening the app but must be on this specific canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-draw-on-canvas/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#2) will help. You mustn't call view lifecycle events in constructor.

`onMeasure(width, height);
 onSizeChanged(width, height,100, 100);
 onDraw(drawCanvas);`

This [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/142-android-custom-view-tutorial) will be useful too.